# how to write this sql query in model of Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE customer_name NOT IN ( 'IBM', 'Hewlett Packard', 'Microsoft' );
```

I want to write a query in my task which is similar to the above query,and my task is in ruby on rails.

Comment: Have a look here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html It should solve your question and discribes how to do querys in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ***Rails 4***, the following will do

```
Customer.where.not(customer_name: ['IBM', 'Hewlett Packard', 'Microsoft'])
```

For Rails versions lower than ***Rails 4***, the below will work

```
Customer.where("customer_name NOT IN (?)", ['IBM', 'Hewlett Packard', 'Microsoft'])
```